# Free MongoDB storage engine

Tags: gratis, open-source, database, mongodb, in-memory-database

In [MongoDB docs here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/storage-engines/), you will find that the listed MongoDB storage engines are:

1. WiredTiger
2. MMAPv1
3. In-Memory Storage Engine

Are there any other storage engines available? Must be free, or even open source.

Comment: For anyone else who wants some background on this posting, [MongoDB revs you up: What storage engine is right for you? (Part 1)](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/01/06/mongodb-revs-you-up-what-storage-engine-is-right-part-1/). There seem to be three parts to this series of blogs with a link at the end of each to the next one. Enjoy!

Comment: Is there any reason why the 3 options you mention do not fulfill your needs, or have room for improvement (for instance performance)? Or do these 3 options perfectly fulfill your needs?

Comment: I'm basically trying to get options so that I can analyse and make a choice.

Answer (score 1):

Available storage engines in the MongoDB Community Server (as at MongoDB 3.6) are:

- [WiredTiger](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/) (default storage engine since MongoDB 3.2)
- [MMAPv1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/mmapv1/) (original storage engine; will be deprecated in MongoDB 4.0)

MongoDB Enterprise Server (commercial edition) adds:

- [Encrypted Storage Engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-encryption-at-rest/#encrypted-storage-engine) (MongoDB 3.2+)
- [In-Memory Storage Engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/inmemory/) (MongoDB 3.2.6+)

Outside of these officially supported storage engines there is also [MongoRocks](http://mongorocks.org/) (RocksDB) which you can either build from source or find in a community distribution like Percona Server for MongoDB. [Development activity on MongoRocks](https://github.com/mongodb-partners/mongo-rocks/graphs/contributors) (as compared to [development activity on WiredTiger](https://github.com/wiredtiger/wiredtiger/graphs/contributors)) is significantly less active in terms of contributors and commits.

I'm not aware of any third party storage engines with significant adoption. My recommendation would be to use the default storage engine (WiredTiger) if you want the most thoroughly tested and supported option with timely access to new MongoDB features.

Answer (score 0):

[There's also TokuMX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TokuMX) from Tokutek, which is not not strictly an engine but a fork, however its main feature is that it replaces b-trees with fractal tree indexes in the engine. This is analogous to [TokuDB for MySQL/MariaDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TokuDB).

It appears to be abandoned, though, with the last commits in 2015.

Comment: Tokutek was acquired by Percona in 2015 and the last release of TokuMX was later that year. [TokuMX was officially EoL'd in April, 2017](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/04/26/migrate-tokumx-percona-server-mongodb/). TokuMX predates MongoDB 3.0 and the storage engine API used in modern versions of MongoDB.

Comment: There was also a TokuMXse variant (later renamed to PerconaFT) using the MongoDB storage engine API, but this was [deprecated in June, 2016](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/06/16/mongorocks-deprecating-perconaft-mongodb-optimistic-locking/) in favour of MongoRocks, which in turn was [deprecated in May, 2018](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/05/10/why-weve-deprecated-mongorocks-in-percona-server-for-mongodb-3-6/).